# Is possible to use selenium scripts for load and performance testing

Tags: testing

1) Is there is any way to use selenium functional test scripts for load and performance testing.

2) Or any other tool for handle both functional and load using same script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with running selenium tests as load testing, and it can be done with TestNG or Visual Studio's load test wizard is that it will be very machine intensive as each test will run in it's own browser window.

A better option would be Grinder or JMeter